# Swift 3: Array to Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, filter, swift3

I have a large array and need to access it by a key (a lookup) so I need to create Dictionary.  Is there a built in function in Swift 3.0 to do so, or do I need to write it myself?

First I will need it for a class with key "String" and later on maybe I will be able to write a template version for general purpose (all types of data and key).

Comment: In array you have only values in dictionary you have key value. What keys should be ?

Comment: `So I need to create Dictionary` But what would be the keys?

Comment: How did you wind up with an array in the first place? If there's a strict format with elements that can be used as keys it shouldn't be too hard. Could you perhaps show us a piece of the array?

Comment: I think I need a closure, which delivers the key, e.g. an member of the class. To make it simple my first attempt would be a string key.

Comment: Are the keys unique over all elements in the array? If so, it will have the same count as your array, so why do you need a dictionary?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
extension Array {
    public func toDictionary<Key: Hashable>(with selectKey: (Element) -> Key) -> [Key:Element] {
        var dict = [Key:Element]()
        for element in self {
            dict[selectKey(element)] = element
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

You can now do:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var identifier: String
}

let arr = [Person(name: "John", surname: "Doe", identifier: "JOD"),
           Person(name: "Jane", surname: "Doe", identifier: "JAD")]
let dict = arr.toDictionary { $0.identifier }

print(dict) // Result: ["JAD": Person(name: "Jane", surname: "Doe", identifier: "JAD"), "JOD": Person(name: "John", surname: "Doe", identifier: "JOD")]
```

---

If you'd like your code to be more general, you could even add this extension on `Sequence` instead of `Array`:

```
extension Sequence {
    public func toDictionary<Key: Hashable>(with selectKey: (Iterator.Element) -> Key) -> [Key:Iterator.Element] {
        var dict: [Key:Iterator.Element] = [:]
        for element in self {
            dict[selectKey(element)] = element
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

Do note, that this causes the Sequence to be iterated over and could have side effects in some cases.

Comment: Yes, you could be right. :-) Looks excellent, but I'm a beginner so I have to work through it for understanding how this is done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Peter71 I've added a bit of a demonstration on how to use it, feel free to ask any specific questions if you get stuck on anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got it. Now I will test how fast it is. But what are the side effects???

Comment: @Peter71 some Sequences can only be iterated over once, for more information, check out [Apple's documentation of Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence). Unless your Array is huge, performance shouldn't be an issue. And it will be hard to beat a good old fashioned for loop (and in this case I think the version with reduce isn't particularly elegant anyway).

Comment: Array is large (20.000 elements), but any other way is slow, so I will give it a try. And that .reduce is not optimal, I will believe in you. :-) I don't have any experince in this.

Comment: @Peter71 if the possible side effects bother you, you can implement this in an extension of `Collection` instead, that's the most general Protocol for Collections that can be iterated over non destructively and multiple times.

Comment: Fair enough but I think `rethrows` is missed in this solution. Thus it doesn't  conform well to other collection methods.

Comment: If variables of structures are optional it creates dictionary with keys and values containing optional("Value"), how to handle this situation

Answer (score 115):

Is that it (in Swift 4)?

```
let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: array.map{ ($0.key, $0) })
```

**Note:**
As mentioned in the comment, using `uniqueKeysWithValues` would give a fatal error (`Fatal error: Duplicate values for key: 'your_key':`) if you have duplicated keys.

If you fear that may be your case, then you can use [`init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init) e.g.

```
let pairsWithDuplicateKeys = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 4)] // or `let pairsWithDuplicateKeys = array.map{ ($0.key, $0) }`

let firstValues = Dictionary(pairsWithDuplicateKeys, uniquingKeysWith: { (first, _) in first })

print(firstValues)

//prints ["a": 1, "b": 2]

let lastValues = Dictionary(pairsWithDuplicateKeys, uniquingKeysWith: { (_, last) in last })

print(lastValues)

//prints ["a": 3, "b": 4]
```

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal - there's a variant `uniquingKeysWith` for when there may be dupes!

Comment: @Fattie Thanks for the information. Although, I can't try it right now. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: You should use `.lazy.map` to prevent the intermediate copying and array allocation.

Comment: When you can have duplicates a simple loop may be more readable than `uniquingKeysWith`.

Answer (score 64):

On Swift 4, you can achieve this by using **Dictionary's** `grouping:by:` initializer

For ex: 
You have class named **A**

```
class A {

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    // .
    // .
    // .
    // other declations and implementions
}
```

Next, you have an array of objects of type **A**

```
let a1 = A(name: "Joy")
let a2 = A(name: "Ben")
let a3 = A(name: "Boy")
let a4 = A(name: "Toy")
let a5 = A(name: "Tim")

let array = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

Let's say you want to create a Dictionary by grouping all the names by their first letter. You use Swifts `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` to achieve this

```
let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { $0.name.first! })
// this will give you a dictionary
// ["J": [a1], "B": [a2, a3], "T": [a4, a5]]
```

[source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init)

Note however that the resulting Dictionary "dictionary" is of type

```
[String : [A]]
```

it ***is not*** of type

```
[String : A]
```

as you may expect.  (Use `#uniqueKeysWithValues` to achieve the latter.)

Comment: This is the best and correct answer. All the other answers misses the point. Of course one could iterate over an array and copy values to a dictionary. The whole point is to do this using a  _functioal_ construct, which has the possible added benefit of being lazy.

Comment: @SteveKuo it's better than the other answers which are rubbish, but it's wrong  :)  You simply use `uniqueKeysWithValues` , that's all there is to it.  `grouping#by` gives you *an array of the class* as each value. You simply use `uniqueKeysWithValues` to convert arrays to dictionaries.

Answer (score 20):

As others already said, we need to understand which are the keys.

However I am trying to provide a solution to my interpretation of your question.

```
struct User {
    let id: String
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

> Here I am assuming that 2 users with the same `id` cannot exist

```
let users: [User] = ...

let dict = users.reduce([String:User]()) { (result, user) -> [String:User] in
    var result = result
    result[user.id] = user
    return result
}
```

Now `dict` is a dictionary where the `key` is the `user id` and the `value` is the `user value`.

To access a user via its `id` you can now simply write

```
let user = dict["123"]
```

### Update #1: General approach

Given an array of a given type `Element`, and a closure that determine the `key` of an `Element`, the following generic function will generate a `Dictionary` of type `[Key:Element]`

```
func createIndex<Key, Element>(elms:[Element], extractKey:(Element) -> Key) -> [Key:Element] where Key : Hashable {
    return elms.reduce([Key:Element]()) { (dict, elm) -> [Key:Element] in
        var dict = dict
        dict[extractKey(elm)] = elm
        return dict
    }
}
```

Example

```
let users: [User] = [
    User(id: "a0", firstName: "a1", lastName: "a2"),
    User(id: "b0", firstName: "b1", lastName: "b2"),
    User(id: "c0", firstName: "c1", lastName: "c2")
 ]

let dict = createIndex(elms: users) { $0.id }
// ["b0": {id "b0", firstName "b1", lastName "b2"}, "c0": {id "c0", firstName "c1", lastName "c2"}, "a0": {id "a0", firstName "a1", lastName "a2"}]
```

### Update #2

As noted by *Martin R* the reduce will create a new dictionary for each iteration of the related closure. This could lead to huge memory consumption.

Here's another version of the `createIndex` function where the space requirement is O(n) where n is the length of elms.

```
func createIndex<Key, Element>(elms:[Element], extractKey:(Element) -> Key) -> [Key:Element] where Key : Hashable {
    var dict = [Key:Element]()
    for elm in elms {
        dict[extractKey(elm)] = elm
    }
    return dict
}
```

Comment: Yeess! :-) This looks great: using reduce. I will take this. For improvement a template would be excellent using a class type and a closure to deliver the specialist key from an unknown member variable.

Comment: Note that this creates a new dictionary in each iteration step, so it might not be the most performant solution for large arrays. – See https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/ for some thoughts on using `reduce` for mapping operations.

Comment: @Peter71: I added in `Update#1` the general function you requested.

Comment: @MartinR: You are right; I added in `Update#2` a more classic approach with Space Complexity O(n). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you too. It looks a little bit similar to overactors solution, so I think we reached the optimal code from both sides.  Great!

Comment: @Peter71: Yes I didn't notice there was already a similar solution by _@overactors_ :)

Comment: You can now use Swift's `.reduce(into: ...)` (as opposed to `.reduce(_)`) to allow the starting value to be mutated rather than copied.

Answer (score 14):

```
let pills = ["12", "34", "45", "67"]
let kk = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: pills.map{ ($0, "number") })

["12": "number", "67": "number", "34": "number", "45": "number"]
```

swift5 swift4

Answer (score 9):

The following converts an array to a dictionary.

```
let firstArray = [2,3,4,5,5] 

let dict = Dictionary(firstArray.map { ($0, 1) } , uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

Comment: Only if there are no duplicates for `key`. In this example there is: `5`.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5

```
extension Array {

    func toDictionary() -> [Int: Element] {
        self.enumerated().reduce(into: [Int: Element]()) { $0[$1.offset] = $1.element }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This extension works for **all sequences** (including arrays) and lets you select both **key and value**:

```
extension Sequence {
    public func toDictionary<K: Hashable, V>(_ selector: (Iterator.Element) throws -> (K, V)?) rethrows -> [K: V] {
        var dict = [K: V]()
        for element in self {
            if let (key, value) = try selector(element) {
                dict[key] = value
            }
        }

        return dict
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let nameLookup = persons.toDictionary{($0.name, $0)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift way:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func toDictionary<Key: Hashable>(with selectKey: (Element) -> Key) -> [Key: Element] {
        reduce(into: [:]) { $0[selectKey($1)] = $1 }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let arr = [Person(id: 1, name: "Alan")]
arr.toDictionary { $0.id }
// [1: Person(id: 1, name: "Alan")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do it simply,

```
let items = URLComponents(string: "https://im.qq.com?q=13&id=23")!.queryItems!

var dic = [String: Any?]()
items.foreach {
    dic[$0.name] = $0.value
}
```

`reduce` is not very suitable,

```
let dic: [String: Any?] = items.reduce([:]) { (result: [String: Any?], item: URLQueryItem) -> [String: Any?] in
   var r = result
   r[item.name] = item.value // will create an copy of result!!!!!!
   return r
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Compatible with Swift 5 Standard Library (Xcode 10.2+ , iOS 12.2).*

Here's an example of usage of an initializer `init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`

The input `let array: [String] = Locale.isoRegionCodes` is an array of ISO31661-2 codes represented by a string.

```
let countryCodeAndName: [String: String] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Locale.isoRegionCodes.map { ($0, Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0) ?? "")} )
```

Returned dictionary, will list all regions with ISO31661-2 code as a key and a localized region name as a value.

Output:

```
...
"PL":"Poland"
"DE":"Germany"
"FR":"France"
"ES":"Spain"
...
```

**Example 2:**

```
let dictionary: [String: String] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: [ ("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2")] )
```

Output:

```
["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
```

**Important:**

Precondition: The sequence must not have duplicate keys.

Code below will crash an app:

```
let digitWords = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "five"]
let wordToValue = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(digitWords, 1...6))
```

with:

> Fatal error: Duplicate values for key: 'five'

Answer (score 1):

As i understand from you're question you would like to convert to `Array` to `Dictionary`.

In my case i create `extension` for the `Array` and keys for the dictionary will be indexes of the `Array`.

Example:

```
var intArray = [2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1]

extension Array where Element: Any {

    var toDictionary: [Int:Element] {
        var dictionary: [Int:Element] = [:]
        for (index, element) in enumerate() {
            dictionary[index] = element
        }
        return dictionary
    }

}

let dic = intArray.toDictionary
```

Comment: Yes, this does the job, but "manualy". Everything is handled by individual code. I'm looking for a general solution using build-in function (as seen above .reduce)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the pattern set out by map and reduce in swift you could do something nice and functional like this:

```
extension Array {
    func keyBy<Key: Hashable>(_ keyFor: (Element) -> Key) -> [Key: Element] {
        var ret = [Key: Element]()
        for item in self{
            ret[keyFor(item)] = item
        }
        return ret
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Dog {
    let id: Int
}

let dogs = [Dog(id: 1), Dog(id: 2), Dog(id: 3), Dog(id: 4)]
let dogsById = dogs.keyBy({ $0.id }) 
            // [4: Dog(id: 4), 1: Dog(id: 1), 3: Dog(id: 3), 2: Dog(id: 2)]
```