# Array.reduce cannot assign through subscript: 'x' is a 'let' constant

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to use the `reduce`function on an array:

```
var fields = ["gender", "name", "nickname"]
var stats = fields.reduce([String:String]()) { (res, field) -> [String:String] in
  res[field] = json[field] ?? ""
  return res
}
```

It's just going through the `fields` array and assigns values from json object to `res`.

Seems simple to me but the compiler keeps saying:

> error: cannot assign through subscript: 'res' is a 'let' constant

on the line:

```
res[field] = json[field] ?? ""
```

It doesn't make any sense to me because I've never specified `res` or `stats` as `let`.

Comment: ofcourse you made res as let, where is it declared as var?

Comment: @Lu_ i'm looking at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791331/8643650

Comment: exactly, and where did you ser res as var? it is done in example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Closure parameters (unless declared with `inout`) are implicitly constants, as if declared with `let`.
If you want to modify it then you have to make mutable copy first:

```
let stats = fields.reduce([String:String]()) { (res, field) -> [String:String] in
    var res = res
    res[field] = json[field] ?? ""
    return res
}
```

As of **Swift 4** you can use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce):

```
let stats = fields.reduce(into: [String:String]()) { (res, field) in
    res[field] = json[field] ?? ""
}
```

Here `res` is an "inout" parameter and can be mutated in the closure.
This is far more efficient, because no copies are made in each
iteration step.

See also [SE-0171 Reduce with inout](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md).

---

A different Swift 4 solution would be create a new dictionary
by mapping each field to a key/value pair:

```
let stats = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: fields.map { ($0, json[$0] ?? "") })
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift parameters are immutables, you cannot change a dictionary received as parameter

```
res[field] = json[field] ?? ""
```

### Solution

```
let json: [String:Any] = ...
let fields = ["gender", "name", "nickname"]
let stats = fields.reduce([String:String]()) { (res, field) -> [String:String] in
    var res = res
    res[field] = (json[field] as? String) ?? ""
    return res
}
```