# how to send codable struct to server with swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I'm almost new to swift and I'm facing a runtime error which says:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

I have an Array of data that I need to send to the API.

The code below shows the model that the API will accept

***Json***

```
 {
  "items": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "ID": 9827
    }

  ]
}
```

my struct:

```
    struct Itemm : Codable {
    var unitNo:Int? 
    var personId:Int?

    enum iItem : Int ,CodingKey{
        case unitNo , personId
    }

}
struct welcome : Codable {
    var items : [Itemm?]
}
typealias welcomeList = [welcome]
```

the code below shows the way I'm creating my array and trying to send it to Server

```
    var items = [Itemm]()
            for indexPath in self.selectedCells {
                let data = self.data![indexPath.section]
                let contact = data.contacts[indexPath.row]
                let newItem = Itemm(unitNo: data.unitNo, personId: contact?.id)
                items.append(newItem)
            }
    //      let welcome = welcome(items: items)
            print(items)
            let welcomee = welcome(items: items)
            print(welcomee)
            do{

       //I found this part on stackoverflow
            let dict = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Int].self, from: JSONEncoder().encode(items))
                print("===============")
                print(dict)
                print("********************")
                Presenter.sendSmsForAllTheMembers(AptId: aptId, data: dict)
            }
            catch let error
            {
                print(error)
            }
```

I'm using Alamofire and Moya library.
 does anybody know how should I send my request to API?

```
func sendSmsForAllTheMembers(AptId:String , data:[String:Any])
{
    ApiGenerator.request(targetApi: ApartemanService.sendSms(aptId: AptId, data: data), responseModel: Nil.self, success: { (response) in
        if response.response.statusCode == 200 {
            self.view?.SendingSmsSuccess()
        }else {
            do{

                var errorMessage = try response.response.mapString()
                errorMessage = errorMessage.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "",
                                                                 options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
                print("errorMessage =============")
                print(errorMessage)
                self.view?.SendingSmsFailed(errorMessage: errorMessage)

            }catch let error{
                print(error)
                self.view?.SendingSmsFailed(errorMessage: "خطا در ارتباط با سرور")
            }

        }

    }) { (error) in
        self.view?.SendingSmsFailed(errorMessage: "خطا در ارتباط با سرور")
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Moya but, just as a glance, it seems like your `var items = [Itemm]()` is an array, and you are using the `JSONEncoder` to encode this and send it as a dictionary.  You may want to *try* converting the `items` array to a dictionary (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791084/swift-3-array-to-dictionary)) and determine if that makes a difference.  Note that that may lead to parsing issues on the server side, but it'd be interesting to know if that resolves Xcode's error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding is fine, but the re-decoding fails.

The error message is pretty clear. You have to decode an array.

```
try JSONDecoder().decode([[String: Int]].self...
```

But as the API expects a dictionary you might create the dictionary directly

```
var items = [[String:Int]]()
for indexPath in self.selectedCells {
    let data = self.data![indexPath.section]
    let contact = data.contacts[indexPath.row]
    items.append(["Number" : data.unitNo, "ID" : contact!.id])
}
let welcome = ["items" : items]
print(welcome)
Presenter.sendSmsForAllTheMembers(AptId: aptId, data: welcome)
```

Comment: I get an error when I try this!!    Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Int]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Comment: There are some inconsistencies in the code. The `iItem` enum has no effect and the keys in the JSON don't match the struct members.

Comment: the first part of the code that shows the json is one of the problems that I don't know that my struct is correct or not!

Comment: I was just answering the question to resolve the **type mismatch** error. To resolve subsequent errors – as I said already – there are too many inconsistencies and missing information in the code. For example why do you encode and decode right back? Why do you encode `items` instead of more likely `welcomee`? What is `sendSmsForAllTheMembers`?

Comment: I added sendSmsForAllTheMembers

Comment: as I said in the question , I found "            let dict = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Int].self, from: JSONEncoder().encode(items))
" on the stackOverFlow

Comment: Sorry it's still confusing what you are going to accomplish. `sendSmsForAllTheMembers` expects a dictionary (`[String:Any]`), it seems there is no JSON involved at all. So rather than creating the structs create the dictionary direclty.

Comment: what should I send to API based on the json in my question, dictionary or something else? if I'm doing it wrong , what should I do  or what should I change in my code?

Comment: I updated the answer with a suggestion but I have no idea if it works.

Comment: Your update answer totally worked but as soon as I get status code 200 it starts the app from the beginning!!!  why should this happen when I have not implemented a dismiss code !!!:|

Comment: Please ask a new question.