# Why can't I call reduce(into:) on an array literal in Xcode 9.2?

Tags: arrays, swift, reduce, type-inference

I was looking for a way to map an array to a dictionary and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839132/5133585). It was very helpful. I copied the code in that post into a playground and it works.

Then I decided to play around with it more:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(into: [Int: String](), {$0[$1] = $1.description})
```

I expected it to return `[1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"]` but a compiler error occurs:

> Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

I tried to reduce to an array instead:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(into: [Int](), {$0.append($1)}) // I am aware that this is pointless
```

But it still does not compile. The message is different this time:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Then I found out that this is because of the fact that I am using array literals, for if I declared a constant array first, then call `reduce` on it, no errors appear:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
arr.reduce(into: [Int: String](), {$0[$1] = $1.description})
```

The normal `reduce` seems to work fine with literals though:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(0, +)
```

Why does `reduce(into:)` not work with array literals?

Comment: Both your first and second code  compile and run without problems in my Xcode 9.3.1.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, I haven't updated Xcode in a while and am using Xcode 9.2. Could that be a fixed compiler bug then?

Comment: Just curious, does `([1,2,3] as [Int]).reduce(into: [Int: String](), {$0[$1] = $1.description})` work with Xcode 9.2?

Comment: Apparently this: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6995 – which has been fixed now.

Comment: @vacawama Yes it does! I thought `[1,2,3]` is always treated as `[Int]`...

Comment: @MartinR Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Well `[1,2,3]` is frequently inferred to be `[Int]`, but if the type inference is broken as it seems to be in this instance, then giving it a hint helps.  You can pass `[1,2,3]` to a method that is expecting `[Double]` or `[Float]` and it will be inferred to be the right type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug: [SR-6995 Unable to infer type with `reduce(into:)`](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6995) which has been fixed in the
meantime, the error won't occur anymore with Xcode 9.3.1.

Interestingly, is suffices to add *any* additional statement to 
the closure to make it compile in Xcode 9.2:

```
let d = [1,2,3].reduce(into: [Int: String](), {
    () ; $0[$1] = $1.description
})
```

Another option is to specify the accumulator type in the closure
explicitly:

```
let d = [1,2,3].reduce(into: [Int: String](), { (accum: inout [Int: String], elem) in
    accum[elem] = elem.description
})
```

Or, as @vacawama noticed, annotate the array type explicitly:

```
let d = ([1,2,3] as [Int]).reduce(into: [Int: String](), {
    $0[$1] = $1.description
})
```